# striptags not removing <p> tag?

Tags: templating

I've seen how you can remove html tags with twig in other posts here so I am using:

```
<p class="slider--text">{{ product.intro|striptags('<p>')|raw }}</p>
```

To remove the `<p>` tag that redactor adds automatically. However for some reason it is not removing it. Anyone have any ideas. Have I missed something glaringly obvious?

Cheers

Answer (score 13):

Actually, the `striptags` filter (which is just a wrapper for the PHP [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function) removes all HTML tags *except the ones you pass in*.

In other words, if you want to remove `<p>` tags, just use the `striptags` filter without any parameters:

```
{# Will remove all HTML tags #}
<p class="slider--text">{{ product.intro|striptags|raw }}</p>
```

If there are other tags you want to retain, you'll need to pass those in:

```
{# Will remove all tags except <br> and <img> #}
<p class="slider--text">{{ product.intro|striptags('<br><img>')|raw }}</p>
```

For a different take on stripping tags, you can use [the Retcon plugin](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft) (which I wrote). With Retcon, you can remove all `<p>` tags (and only `<p>` tags; retaining their contents as well as all other tags) easily by using the [`retconChange`](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft/wiki/Change) filter:

```
<p class="slider--text">{{ product.intro|retconChange('<p>', false) }}</p>
```